# Displaying multiplied number in asterisks (in C)

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop

[image: Problem 4]

I'm new to Loops and I'm trying to understand how will I be able to display those asterisks, such that each row will have its respective number of asterisks.

I've tried doing this, but I'm having a hard time with what to do next.

The problem is that the output only shows 3 asterisks for each row instead expected output on the first image. [output problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GQAC.jpg)

```
void displayAst (int b) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= b ; i++) {
        printf ("*");
    }
}

void displayMulti (int a) {
    

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        
        printf ("\n%d x %d = ", a, i);

        displayAst (a); 
        
            }
    }

int main () {

    int nNum;

    printf ("Enter Number: "); 
    scanf ("%d", &nNum);

    displayMulti (nNum);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what your program does wrong! So, this is a bit inanswerable :)
Is `displayAst (a);` *really* correct? Are you not missing something?

Comment: You tell the user `a * i =`  and then only print `a` symbols. What happened to `* i` part?

Comment: You should also always check return value of `scanf` to detect if there was an error.

Comment: Also, a remark on coding style: `int i; for(i = 1; i < condition; i++)` is C from 1989. Since C99, you would probably prefer `for(int i = 1; i < condition; i++)`. Putting the `int i` declaration inside the `for`-loop header makes your code not only more compact, it also limits the *scope* where that `i` exists: inside the loop, not outside. You can avoid having to mentally carry around more variables at every point in your code if you do that :)

Comment: Hello @Gerhardh, yes upon compiling the code I have not seen any errors regarding the scanf.

Comment: There will be if the user types `abc`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the remark! and I have also updated the post on what the problem is.

Comment: @KenKeneshel but you didn't seem to have thought about the second half of my remark, sadly :(

Comment: Checking a return value is not done at compile time. It is done at runtime. It is not related to compiler errors.

Comment: `displayAst (a);` -> `displayAst (i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is at the following line

```
displayAst (a);
```

you are always passing a; which in your case is the input number from the user. i.e. 3. Instead the method should be

```
displayAst (a*i);
```

The number of stars that must be printed after the multiplication.

I know you are beginning to code. If you start using a debugger, you can yourself solve these issues. Plus a debugger would give you insight how your code works.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. If I may ask, do you have some good recommendations on what debuggers should I use?

Comment: I would start with gdb if you are developing on Linux and using gcc compiler. On windows, if you are using a specific IDE e.g visual studio, then visual studio comes with its own debugger. Finally if you find the answer helpful, please do accept it as final answer

Answer (score 1):

At your `displayMulti()` method, where you are calling `displayMulti(a)`, the method should be `displayMulti(a*i)`.

**Solution:**

```
 void displayAst (int b) {
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= b ; i++) {
            printf ("*");
        }
    }
    
    void displayMulti (int a) {
        
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
            
            printf ("\n%d x %d = ", a, i);
    
            displayAst (a*i); 
            
                }
        }
    
    int main () {
    
        int nNum;
    
        printf ("Enter Number: "); 
        scanf ("%d", &nNum);
    
        displayMulti (nNum);
        
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I see now what I did wrong. Thank you!